# Yii2: how to write SQL Query to increment value or decrement value when new record gets created in database?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I have two tables

```
room_type          create_bookings

r_type             room_status
total
total_booked
total_remain
```

where

`r_type` is different types of room available e.g AC or Non AC,

`total` is no. of rooms available

`total_booked` - no of rooms booked for particular room type

`total_remain` - is no. of rooms available for particular room type

`room_staus` - e.g CHECKIN or CHECKOUT

I need to write query so that whenever new booking is created in `create_bookings` table for the particular 
`r_type` count should increment +1 in `total_booked` and -1 in `total_remain` and 
when status got changed to CHECKOUT in `room_status` in `create_bookings` table, count should -1 in `total_booked` and +1 in `total_remain`

Something like:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE room_type AFTER INSERT ON create_bookings FOR ROW(where room type selected by user)
    BEGIN
    UPDATE r_type SET (NEW.total_booked = OLD.total_booked + 1)
    UPDATE r_type SET (NEW.total_remain = OLD.total_remain - 1)
    END
Not able to write for status change query
```

Implementing in Yii2

Any help would be appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Use `afterSave()` of your model, or just create trigger.

Comment: Ya,  but what about query, i need query

Comment: you can use `updateCounters` on `afterSave`. see details about `updateCounters` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#updateCounters%28%29-detail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2: not able to update column value by + 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623067/yii2-not-able-to-update-column-value-by-1)