# Yii2: not able to update column value by + 1

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, yii2

I need to update column value by + 1 when new records get created :

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new CreateBookings();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE room_types SET total_booked = total_booked + 1 WHERE room_type = '$model->room_type' ")->execute();
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                 return $this->render('create', [
                 'model' => $model,
                 ]);
            }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong please guide :)

Comment: Is the exact error message or unexpected behaviour  classified for some reason?

Comment: im not getting any error but, its not returning any result either

Comment: If seems that it's better to update counter right after you successfuly `save()` record. `if ($model->save()) { /*update counter and redirec*/ }`

Comment: @SiZE.. its not working either

Comment: @SiZE how can I use ` Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE room_types SET total_booked = total_booked + 1 WHERE room_type = '$model->room_type' ")->execute();` query in behaviors?

Comment: @Saurabh you may get as an example this behaviour http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html and make the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE room_types SET total_booked=total_booked+1 WHERE room_type = '$model->room_type' ")->execute();
```

OR

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new CreateBookings();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

    $RoomType = new room_types(); // room type replace with model name
    $RoomType->updateCounters(['total_booked' => 1]);

      $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Official [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#updateCounters()-detail)

Comment: its not increasing the counter

Comment: have you create model for room_types? like CreateBookings()

Comment: yes its already there `$types = new Roomtypes();`... updateCounter function should run after model got save, because i tried in `actionUpdate` its working fine but not working in `actionCreate`

Comment: I see!! Updates one or several counter columns for the current AR object. it will not work with actionCreate.

Comment: check my updated answer and copy query from my answer, I think there is space issue `total_booked+1`

Comment: i use createCommand for multi update in one query but dont support updateCounters. please help me.

Answer (score 7):

You should like the following codes:

```
    $post = \backend\models\Posts::find()->where(['postID' => 25])->one();
    $post->updateCounters(['total_booked' => 1]);
```